# Htaccess - The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server in flynax

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new htaccess and flynax, I have installed flynax on localhost the path localhost/flynax. It shows the index page content but when I click on anything it shows the error the requested URL /index.php was not found on this server. I tried somany things all shows error. like changing rewritebase /flynax, Rewritebase http://localhost/flynax/ .. Please help me  . I think the problem lies in the htaccess. following is the htaccess in the flynax folder project main folder

```
        # Configures the footer on server-generated documents
        ServerSignature Off

        # enable apache morRewrite module
        RewriteEngine on

        # The URL prefix to be used for per-directory
        #RewriteBase /
        RewriteBase /


        # Block BAD user agents
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
        # Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

        # Return 403 Forbidden error.
        #RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
        RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

        # The following rules are for bandwidth-hogging download tools
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            SetEnvIf user-agent "libwww-perl" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "Download Demon" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "GetRight" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "GetWeb!" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "Go!Zilla" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "Go-Ahead-Got-It" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "GrabNet" stayout=1
            SetEnvIf user-agent "TurnitinBot" stayout=1

            # This line denies access to all of the above tools
            deny from env=stayout
        </IfModule>

        # Block possible mySQL injections
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT|CONNECT|HEAD|TRACE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|">|"<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999} [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC]
        # Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

        # Return 403 Forbidden error.
        RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

        # set files headers
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|htc)$">
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public, must-revalidate"
            </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>

        # deflate static content
        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/x-component text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
        </IfModule>

        # allow request methods
        <Limit POST PUT DELETE GET OPTIONS HEAD>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from All
        </Limit>

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

        # non .html redirect
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-z]+)$ [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^([^\/]{3,})/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [NC,L,R=301]

        # non trailing redirect
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-z]+|[\/]|\?.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-z]+|[\/])$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [NC,L,R=301]

        # define system languages
        #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

        # define paging
        RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).html$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 [QSA,L]

        # define listing
        RewriteRule ^(([\w\-\_]+)?/)([^/]+)(/.+)-l?([0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=$2&rlVareables=$3$4&listing_id=$5 [QSA,L]

        # wildcard request
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.|m\. [NC]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.{2,} [NC] # 1 is localhost usage, 2 is glabal usage
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\..+\.+ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+) [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=%1&wildcard&rlVareables=$1 [QSA,L]

        # account request (sub-directory)
        RewriteRule ^((\w{2})/)?([\w-_]{3,})$ index.php?page=$3&lang=$2&account_request [QSA,L]

        # define single pages
        RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

        # define other pages
        RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.html|/+)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 [QSA,L]

        # Google and Yahoo sitemap
        RewriteRule ^([a-z_]*)?sitemap([0-9]*).xml$ plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=google&number=$2&mod=$1 [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule ^yahoo-sitemap.txt$ /plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=yahoo [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule ^urllist.txt$ /plugins/sitemap/sitemap.php?search=urllist [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't know flynax but lots of systems are written with the assumption they'll be installed in the document root. Add `127.0.0.1 flynax.localhost` to your `hosts` file, and set up a vhost for that domain and visit http://flynax.localhost/

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase/flynax/
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have to set your RewriteBase in the .htaccess to the name of the directory where site is installed -

  RewriteBase /flynax/
- If you have already set this up and still have the same problem it's likely you don't have mod_rewrite installed;  you can check it by visiting http://localhost/flynax/admin/?system_info  - it should show you the [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)